# Excel: Remove only true cell content if its in a other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cell A1: House of Cards
Cell B1: of Cards
Cell C1: EXPECTED RESULT House

Cell A2: Looking forward to hear
Cell B2: to hear
Cell C2: EXPECTED RESULT Looking forward

So, C1 should basically be the result of A1 minus exact content of B1. 
and so on.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Likely going to need VBA. Must the text be in order? What if `A1` is `The theory is the key`, and in `B1` is `the`. Do you want both `The` removed?  What have you tried?

Comment: yes...always the individual true value which is next to should be the one which should be removed. if needs to be done via VBA, any idea how?

Comment: Can you clarify with more examples? If `A1` is `Looking forward to hear that and hear it well` and `B1` is `to hear`, what should the output be? `Looking forward that and hear it well`? Or do you want to find `to` and `hear` separately?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1391542/edit) to clarify. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may also prove useful for providing a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,A2,"")
```

Takes the text in `A1` and replaces occurrences of the text in `A2` with the empty string. So "House of Cards" becomes "House" because "of cards" has been replaced with nothing.

Comment: thank you, was exactly what i was looking for!!